# Why is `socket.error` being treated like it doesn't derive from `BaseException`?

Tags: python, django, exception, redis

So I've got Django 2.2.16 running with `redis` library 3.5.0.

Somewhere along the way `Connection` objects of Redis go out of scope and get their `__del__` called, which calls `disconnect()` method on Redis library, it looks as follows:

```py
    def disconnect(self):
        "Disconnects from the Redis server"
        self._parser.on_disconnect()
        if self._sock is None:
            return
        try:
            if os.getpid() == self.pid:
                shutdown(self._sock, socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            self._sock.close()
        except socket.error:
            pass
        self._sock = None
```

Now when this happens this exceptions gets caught:

```
October 12th 2020, 14:28:30.750 Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x7fddec766830>
October 12th 2020, 14:28:30.750 Traceback (most recent call last):
October 12th 2020, 14:28:30.750   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 537, in __del__
October 12th 2020, 14:28:30.750   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 667, in disconnect
October 12th 2020, 14:28:30.750 TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Line 667 in disconnect here refers to this line: `except socket.error:`

Now `socket` is a standard library and its `.error` surely derives from `BaseException`, why do I get this exception at all?